# How to make a pandas dataframe for-loop (for a stock market API)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, finance

I'm trying to get a stock data metric from an API into a Pandas Dataframe (Debt/Equity ratio for a company).

I've been successful in getting the data for a single company, but would like to do it with several companies at a time.

The code I used for a single company is:

```
# Variables
ticker  = "AAPL" 
FMP_API = "<api_key_here>"
data    = "balance-sheet-statement"

def get_jsonparsed_data(url):
    response = urlopen(url)
    data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(data)


# Download info from API
url = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/"+data+"/"+ticker+"?limit=120&apikey="+FMP_API
results = get_jsonparsed_data(url)
df = json_normalize(results)

# Calculate  Debt/Equity Ratio
df[ticker] = df.totalLiabilities / df.totalStockholdersEquity
df = df[["date", ticker]].round(2)

# Convert the column Date, now in string type to a datetime type
# Make the Date Column the Index
# Creating a new dataframe with the new index and add the Date column name
# Dropp the extra Date Column
datetime_series = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
datetime_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(datetime_series.values)
df = df.set_index(datetime_index).rename_axis('date', axis=1)
df.drop('date',axis=1,inplace=True)

df.head()
```

The result I get is:

```
date        AAPL
2020-09-26  3.96
2019-09-28  2.74
2018-09-29  2.41
2017-09-30  1.80
2016-09-24  1.51

date
AAPL    float64
dtype: object
```

What I would like to get is:

```
ticker  = ["AAPL", "FB", "GOOG", "AMZN"]

date        AAPL   FB   GOOG  AMZN
2020-09-26  3.96  0.24  0.44  2.44
2019-09-28  2.74  0.32  0.37  2.63
2018-09-29  2.41  0.16  0.31  2.73
2017-09-30  1.80  0.14  0.29  3.74
2016-09-24  1.51  0.10  0.20  3.32

date
AAPL    float64
FB      float64
GOOG    float64
AMZN    float64
dtype: object
```

I tried using a for loop, but i keep writing over the same dataframe and can only get the values for the last ticker in the list.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a short, representative sample of what `results` looks like for one of the tickers?

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas `merge` to merge two of the same dataframes with different tickers by the same index.

You can also simplify your code where you set the date as the index:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index(date)
```

Comment: But how do you automate the creation of each dataframe. 
Say you wanted to add 50 tickers at at time.

Comment: You can (and should) put all of the code that gathers the data and formats it into a df for any given ticker into a function. Then call the function for every ticker. Combine at end.

Answer (score 0):

Found the anwser.

The idea is to create an empty list and a for loop.

Each loop gets the data from one ticker and in the end we make a dataframe by concatenating the list.

Here is the code:

```
FMP_API = "<api_code_here>"

data    = "balance-sheet-statement"
tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT']
     
df_list = []
     
for ticker in tickers:
    url = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/" + data + "/" + ticker + "?limit=120&apikey=" + FMP_API
    df = pd.read_json(url)
    df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
     
    df[ticker] = df.totalLiabilities / df.totalStockholdersEquity
    df_list.append(df[ticker])
     
df_final = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
print(df_final)
```